# compiling asio library without boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am trying compile the asio without the boost library.
   http://think-async.com/Asio/Documentation

so, I did

```
 ./configure --prefix=/raspberry/asio/product
```

and I got error

```
checking boost/noncopyable.hpp usability... no
checking boost/noncopyable.hpp presence... no
checking for boost/noncopyable.hpp... no
Can't find boost headers. Please check the location of the boost
distribution and rerun configure using the --with-boost=DIR option.
```

I thought this asio doesn't require boost.

So, next I grab the library of asio that with boost and grabbed the boost folder and put into the asio(non boost) folder.

but it still give me the same error.

Comment: what are you trying to configure and build? The Asio library is header only, there is nothing to compile.

Answer (score 9):

```
./configure --prefix=/raspberry/asio/product --without-boost
```

Answer (score 0):

Building ASIO requires the boost headers.  Installing boost onto the system is the easiest way, but you can also do a local install (in one of your directories) and point to it.

Comment: How do I point to boost build when I am building asio?  ./configure --prefix=/asio/product --xxx=/asio_boost/compiled/include.    What's --xxx?